# How can I stop at the first occurrence? - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am facing an issue with Laravel as I am trying to get this to stop on the first occurrence. So as you can see from the code below, I have different types of government in my blade file. The issue is, it loops through all government roles for that type and its firing the count < 1 multiple times and it doesn't look very friendly.

Code:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="higher_government_team">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel panel-body">
                    @if ($royalty->count() < 1)
                        We couldn't find any government roles for this category.
                    @else
                        @foreach($royalty as $key => $governmentRole)
                            @if (count($governmentRole->stats) < 1)
                                There are currently no candigates working in this category.
                            @else
                                @foreach($governmentRole->stats as $governmentMember)
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-left:-40px;">
                                            <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:-16px;"><img src="http://mywebsite.com/os734zl?figure=ch-3030-92.hr-681-34.hd-209-8.lg-3116-106-1408&size=b&direction=3&head_direction=3"></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-9" style="margin-left:40px;">
                                                <h4>{{ $governmentMember->user->username }} <small>{{ $governmentRole->government_title }}</small></h4>
                                                <p><font color="#aaa">{{ $governmentRole->government_department }}</font></p><br>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    @endif

                    @if ($higherGovernment->count() < 1)
                        We couldn't find any government roles for this category.
                    @else
                        @foreach($higherGovernment as $governmentRole)
                            @if (count($governmentRole->stats) < 1)
                                There are currently no candigates working in this category.
                            @else
                                @foreach($governmentRole->stats as $governmentMember)
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-left:-40px;">
                                            <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:-16px;"><img src="http://mywebsite.com/os734zl?figure=ch-3030-92.hr-681-34.hd-209-8.lg-3116-106-1408&size=b&direction=3&head_direction=3"></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-9" style="margin-left:40px;">
                                                <h4>{{ $governmentMember->user->username }} <small>{{ $governmentRole->government_title }}</small></h4>
                                                <p><font color="#aaa">{{ $governmentRole->government_department }}</font></p><br>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="senior_government_team">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel panel-body">
                    @if ($seniorGovernment->count() < 1)
                        We couldn't find any government roles for this category.
                    @else
                        @foreach($seniorGovernment as $governmentRole)
                            @if (count($governmentRole->stats) < 1)
                                There are currently no candigates working in this category.
                            @else
                                @foreach($governmentRole->stats as $governmentMember)
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-left:-40px;">
                                            <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:-16px;"><img src="http://mywebsite.com/os734zl?figure=ch-3030-92.hr-681-34.hd-209-8.lg-3116-106-1408&size=b&direction=3&head_direction=3"></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-9" style="margin-left:40px;">
                                                <h4>{{ $governmentMember->user->username }} <small>{{ $governmentRole->government_title }}</small></h4>
                                                <p><font color="#aaa">{{ $governmentRole->government_department }}</font></p><br>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="junior_government_team">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel panel-body">
                    @if ($juniorGovernment->count() < 1)
                        We couldn't find any government roles for this category.
                    @else
                        @foreach($juniorGovernment as $governmentRole)
                            @if (count($governmentRole->stats) < 1)
                                There are currently no candigates working in this category.
                            @else
                                @foreach($governmentRole->stats as $governmentMember)
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-left:-40px;">
                                            <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:-16px;"><img src="http://mywebsite.com/os734zl?figure=ch-3030-92.hr-681-34.hd-209-8.lg-3116-106-1408&size=b&direction=3&head_direction=3"></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-9" style="margin-left:40px;">
                                                <h4>{{ $governmentMember->user->username }} <small>{{ $governmentRole->government_title }}</small></h4>
                                                <p><font color="#aaa">{{ $governmentRole->government_department }}</font></p><br>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This part of code is firing about 10 times, what I want to do is only fire it once so it looks clean and friendly. I want it to fire once for each tab panel.

```
@if (count($governmentRole->stats) < 1)
    There are currently no candigates working in this category.
@else
```

Current output:
There are currently no candigates working in this category. There are currently no candigates working in this category. There are currently no candigates working in this category. There are currently no candigates working in this category. There are currently no candigates working in this category. There are currently no candigates working in this category. There are currently no candigates working in this category.

What output I want:
There are currently no candigates working in this category.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [@break](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#loops) directive to exit the loop:

```
@if (count($governmentRole->stats) < 1)
    There are currently no candigates working in this category.
    @break
@else
```

Comment: That will stop any further government members being processed.

Comment: @break will exit the loop. If it's not what are you looking for, then I don't understand what are you trying to achieve, sorry.

Comment: I'm trying to skip the 'There are currently no candigates working in this category.' message if its already happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`forelse`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#loops) to do this. `forelse` will loop over the collection or show a message if the collection is empty.

```
@forelse($governmentRole->stats as $governmentMember)
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-left:-40px;">
            <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:-16px;"><img src="http://mywebsite.com/os734zl?figure=ch-3030-92.hr-681-34.hd-209-8.lg-3116-106-1408&size=b&direction=3&head_direction=3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-9" style="margin-left:40px;">
                <h4>{{ $governmentMember->user->username }} <small>{{ $governmentRole->government_title }}</small></h4>
                <p><font color="#aaa">{{ $governmentRole->government_department }}</font></p><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@empty
    There are currently no candigates working in this category.
@endforelse
```

**Update:**

You will have to do the check before starting the loop and ignore empty result sets. You can use Laravel Collections to check if the collection will contain any results. Like so:

```
@if ($royalty->count() < 1)
    We couldn't find any government roles for this category.
@elseif ($royalty->filter(function ($r) { return $r->stats->count() > 0; })->isEmpty()
    There are currently no candigates working in this category.
@else
    @foreach($royalty as $key => $governmentRole)
        <!-- Your loop code, no 'if' needed anymore -->
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Anything to help if I have multiple government types in 1 tab panel?

Comment: Also, this doesn't really help as it still loops the @empty multiple times due to the first foreach.